# Compare() link to be placed in dropdown menu in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, header, navigation, compare

I want to **place the Compare link inside the dropdown** below Wishlist in header links as shown here 
[image]

OR https://prnt.sc/os1u0o.

Can any one tell me how to do that ?

Comment: which theme you are using ?

Comment: @ShafeelSha Smartwave Porto

Comment: can you please share the theme demo link

Comment: @ShafeelSha https://www.portotheme.com/magento/porto/demo5_en

Comment: search this 'compare-link' keyword in your design folder

Comment: can you please find app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Smartwave_Porto/layout/default.xml

Comment: Yes . this is want is defined for header links <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97418/discussion-between-shafeel-sha-and-nafisa).